# Site is redirecting to old domain on button submission, files are linking to old domain

Tags: 7, files, redirection

I have a D7 site at `www.example.com`, an old one, not updated since 2012 (Drupal version 7.34). I made a clone copy with separate clone database under `dev.example.com`

All files like CSS are still linking to `www.example.com` (while they are available at `dev.example.com`).

And most important, on `/admin/` backend when under `dev.example.com` if you click any `Submit` button in any page, it redirects to the `www.example.com` website. So if I submitted any operation at `dev.example.com/admin/*` it redirects to same page at `www.example.com/admin/*`

I've cloned websites million times, I never had this behavior. How do I prevent redirects for files and on submissions?

**update:** I found in `settings.php` I have `$base_url = www.example.com` enabled, can somebody confirm this is the reason?

Comment: Can *you* confirm this *was* the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have to edit it to dev.example.com. In the Drupal code, the modules use a function who returns the base URL. So if this URL is the old site... it resolves to the old site.

It's also used to protect your website against XSS.